# Runtime error 13: Type mismatch on Date using DateSerial

Tags: excel, vba

I get the Error 13 when trying to convert cells formatted like follows to a Date:

> 2017-09-06 00:00:00.0

```
Dim d As Date
d = DateSerial(CInt(Left(Cells(i, 15).Value, 4)), CInt(Mid(Cells(i, 15).Value, 6, 2)), CInt(Mid(Cells(i, 15).Value, 9, 2)))
```

I've been to format them differently to obtain a Date that I can use as is in my code.
But I can't find anything working.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works quite ok for me, probably you are not refering to the correct active sheet and probably this is how the problem comes.

Try to write the:

> 2017-09-06 00:00:00.0

in Range `A1` of a newly created excel sheet and run the following:

```
Public Sub TestMe2()

    Dim d           As Date
    Dim mycell      As Range
    Set mycell = Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

    d = DateSerial(CInt(Left(mycell, 4)), _
                CInt(Mid(mycell.Value, 6, 2)), _
                CInt(Mid(mycell.Value, 9, 2)))

    Debug.Print d

End Sub
```

If you make sure you always refer to the Worksheet (as in the code above, setting `mycell` to `Worksheets(1)`) you will avoid plenty of headaches.

Comment: I actually referenced the wrong column, I looked at it many times but still put the wrong column...
Thanks for making me think about it again!

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested this and does what you requested, where Sheet1.cells(1,1).value holds your 2017-09-06 00:00:00.0:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim val As Variant
    val = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value
    newdate = CDate(val)
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value = newdate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the format you are holding `2017-09-06 00:00:00.0` in your cell, let's use `Range("A1")` for this example.

**Case 1**: It's saved in a format of date and time, then the following code will do:

```
d = CDate(Range("A1").Value)
```

**Case 2**: it's plain text, then you can find the space between the date and time using `Instr`, and later convert it to `Date`.

```
Dim d As Date
Dim xPos As Long

' find the position of the space
xPos = InStr(Range("A1").Value2, " ")

d = CDate(Left(Range("A1").Value2, xPos - 1))
```

Comment: I'll use this code to make mine simpler, but I actually had the wrong column in my cells call..
Thanks a lot for your help and time!